# Backbone.js How to retrieve a model in a nested collection?

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I have a PizzaType model that has a nested collection of Pizzas. The Pizzas Collection is listed based on the Pizza Type. I would like to be able to click on a pizza in the pizzas collection and display its attributes.

What would be the best way to set the url params dynamically? 
The url does not need a route to navigate to for bookmarking and sharing, just to retrieve the specific resource.

I have it so that if someone wants to view the pizza type the url is `pizza_type/:id`
:id is the id belonging to the Pizza Type (parent model)

I currently have it so if a pizza is clicked on in the Pizzas Collection (that belongs to the Pizza Type Model), the path to the pizza resource is not followed; just a region on the page is updated. The url path is needed so jQuery can get the resource to update that region. The url to the pizza is `pizza_types/:pizza_type_id/pizzas/:id` Here, the `:id` is the id belonging to the Pizza Model, and the `:pizza_type_id` is the foreign key that members of the Pizzas Collection share to group them into the collection, that belong to the Pizzas Type Model.

When I click on the pizza (id = 3), I get `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/pizza_types/3/pizzas"`

**Here is the Model and Collection Code:**

```
@Pizzeria.module "Entities", (Entities, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class Entities.PizzaType extends Backbone.Model
    urlRoot: "pizza_types/"

    # creates the nested collection
    initialize: ->
      @pizzas = new Entities.PizzasCollection
      @pizzas.url = @urlRoot + @id + '/pizzas'
      @pizzas.fetch
        reset: true

    parse: (response) ->
      response

  class Entities.PizzaTypesCollection extends Backbone.Collection
    model: Entities.PizzaType
    url: 'pizza_types'
    parse: (response) ->
      response

  # Is there a way to pass in a :pizza_type_id and :id params to pass to the url() so
  # that the specific pizza model can be retrieved from the collection?
  class Entities.Pizza extends Backbone.Model
    url: -> "pizza_types/" + 2 + "/pizzas/" + 4 # <-- Hard coded works, but how to set the params dynamically?

    parse: (data) ->
      data

  class Entities.PizzasCollection extends Backbone.Collection
    model: Entities.Pizza
    url: 'pizzas'
    parse: (data) ->
      data
```

Any suggestions? Is this the proper way, I tried to do this as well:

```
class Entities.Pizza extends Backbone.Model
        urlRoot: -> "pizza_types"

        # I thought I could pass these params in and fetch the correct pizza model, but not working.
        fetch
          pizza_type_id: pizza_type_id
          id: id
          reset: true

        parse: (data) ->
          data
```

**PizzaType Attributes with example data:**

```
  PizzaType: {
     id: 2,
     name: "Gourmet",
     pizzas: [
      0: {
           id: 4,
           pizza_type_id: 2
           name: "gourmet pizza 1"
         },
      1: {
           id: 5,
           pizza_type_id: 2,
           name: "gourmet pizza 2"
         }
     ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For url in pizza model you can specify an attribute like pizza_type for model in initialize function and change url function like this

```
class Entities.Pizza extends Backbone.Model
    initialize: (options)->
        @pizza_type = options.pizza_type if options.pizza_type

    url: ->
      "pizza_types/" + @pizza_type + "/pizzas/" + @id

    parse: (data) ->
      data

class Entities.PizzaType extends Backbone.Model
  urlRoot: "pizza_types/"

  url: ->
    @urlRoot+@id+'/pizzas' if @id

  initialize: ->
    @pizzas = new Entities.PizzasCollection
    @pizzas.fetch reset: true

  parse: (response) -> response
```

In `PizzasCollection` add addOptions so when adding models to collection then backbone add with this default options

```
class Entities.PizzasCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: Entities.Pizza
  addOptions:
    'pizza_type': @id
  url: 'pizzas'
  parse: (data) -> data
```

> `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://localhost:3000/pizza_types/3/pizzas"`

This is a problem with your server, maybe mistyping, or trailing-slash problems or any server problems.

P.S : I recommend using a relational model (with any plugin can do that like [BackboneRelationals](http://backbonerelational.org))

Comment: thanks for the tips. I'll try this on Sunday 9/29/13 when I have access to my computer. I'll give you credit when I attempt. Thank you.